# How to find all properties that have names matching a given regex?

Tags: javascript

How can I find all property names that match a given regexp?

Let's say there is an object `o` that has a property called `thievery`, how can I find this property by searching for `very`?

The problem is that I also don't know what is the name of `o`.

example in console :

```
> o = {}
Object {}

> o.thievery=38.45
38.45

> o
Object {thievery: 38.45}
```

Comment: Do you mean in the dev tools?  Or in code?  Pretty sure JS variable names are not directly accessible in code for security purposes.

Comment: Can you include text of object `o` at Question?

Comment: @anied in dev tools

Comment: Where are you searching for variable?

Comment: @guest271314 in the browser's console or dev tools, let's imagine that I don't know/ remember the name of `o.thievery`, I only remember that there is somewhere a variable ending with `very`.

Comment: `console.dir(o)`?

Comment: Where is the object created?

Comment: These are not "variables". They are "properties", which are quite different things.

Comment: You need to (1) get all the keys (2) loop over them and (3) check to see whether it matches. On which part(s) of this are you stuck? Also, why do you think this problem might be Chrome-specific?

Answer (score 5):

I've written a one liner to search inside an object's keys for a partial string
(o is the object and very the term)

```
 Object.keys(o).find(function(q){return /very/gi.test(q)})
```

could be used in a function of course

```
 function searchObject(_object,term){
     var query = new RegExp(term,'i');
     return Object.keys(_object).find(function(q){return query.test(q)})
 }
```

hope it helps

**update**

since  the OP wanted to search for object and var, I've written a function that searches ALL the window variables for objects with a property key containing the term.

```
function searchForObjectByPartialKey(term){
    var query = new RegExp(term,'i');
    var keys = Object.keys(window);
    var results = [];
    keys.forEach(function(varName,i){
        var windowObj = window[varName];
        if (windowObj && typeof windowObj === 'object'){
            var variable = Object.keys(windowObj).filter(function(q){return query.test(q)});
            if(variable.length){
                results.push({props:variable,obj:varName})
            }
        }
   })
    return results;
}
```

it returns an array of objects of 'props' (property key name) and 'obj' (objects name)

Comment: Thanks ! I might try to make this recursive.

Comment: great! if you want to share it, i'll update my answer for future refrence

Comment: I've stepped up to the challenge and wrote it to search all window objects - this will find you both `o` and the `thievery` key when used like `searchForObjectByPartialKey("very")`

Comment: `find` will return the first match, but he wants to find **all** the matches. In your second example, you are searching properties on `window`, but in spite of his incorrect terminology ("variable" instead of "property"), his question makes quite clear that he actually wants to find matching properties on an object, not properties on the window. Also, why are you using `forEach` and building your own results array instead of just using `filter`?

Comment: none, so I've removed it and also updated the last function to return all matches. as to why I'm searching the window, look up and read the OP's comments - that's what he needs. have a good one @torazaburo

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find all variable names that match a given regexp ?

You mean "properties", not "variables". Variables are names existing at the top of some scope. There is no way to enumerate variables (unless you mean global variables, which are actually properties on the `window` object). The "things" inside an `{}` object, the key/value pairs, are called **properties**. The difference matters. By the way, this has nothing to do with Chrome. It would work the same way in any engine in any browser.

> The problem is that I also don't know what the name of `o` is.

Then you're out of luck. As I said, there's no way to enumerate variables, other than global ones, but you're not using those, right? Anyway, why would you have lost track of your own variables?

#### Basic solution

Loop over the properties, check each one, and if it matches add it to the results:

```js
const results = [];
for (let prop in obj) if (/very/.test(prop)) results.push(prop);
```

Here we are using the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) statement to loop over the properties of the object. You should learn this form if you don't already know it. Then we are using [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to test for a match. That is a common, useful method on `RegExp` which you should also learn. I assume you are familiar with arrays and how to `push` elements onto them.

You can make this into a function, passing in the object to examine and the pattern to match:

```
function getMatchingProps(obj, pattern) {
  const results = [];
  for (let prop in obj) if (pattern/.test(prop)) results.push(prop);
  return results;
}

getMatchingProps(obj, /very/);
```

#### "Functional" solution

A slightly more "functional" approach would be to get the list of keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
```

and then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to just extract the ones that match. `filter` is one of the standard callback-based array methods introduced in ES5, including also `forEach`, `every`, and so on. Very useful and good to know.

```
keys.filter(key => pattern.test(key))
```

In function form:

```
function getMatchingProps(obj, pattern) {
   return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => pattern.test(key));
}
```

Here the `=>` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a new feature introduced in ES6, which makes writing little functions much more compact. If for some reason you do not have arrow functions available in your environment, you can write this as `function(key) { return pattern.test(key); }`.

#### Using higher-order functions

I can extend this solution by defining a way to create a "matcher", for a given pattern, that I can then use to match against any object:

```
function makeMatcher(pattern) {
  return function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => pattern.test(key));
  };
}
```

Now

```
const matchVery = makeMatcher(/very/);
console.log(matchVery(obj1), matchVery(obj2));
```

If you can wrap your head around this--a function which returns a function--you are well on your way to advanced understanding of using functions in JS.